# Office-JS API: Fetching filtered data from table

Tags: javascript, excel, filter, office-js

I am trying to figure out a way to fetch only the filtered values from a table if a filter is active in Office-JS API.

Right now the only way I have figured to fetch all the table data is from the table range values property:

```
var table = tables.getItemAt(0);
var tableRange = table.getRange();
tableRange.load("values");
ctx.sync().then(function () {
    // This returns all the values from the table, and not only the visible data
    var values = tableRange.values;
});
```

Any ideas on how I can proceed to fetch only the visible values from the table if a filter is active?

From previous experience with Office Interop I have achieved the same by looping through the different Areas of the table range, but I am unable to find the equivalent to Areas in Office-JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get only filtered data is through the [Binding.getDataAsync method](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.getdataasync), which takes a [filterType parameter](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/filtertype-enumeration).

```
Office.select("bindings#myTableBinding1").getDataAsync({
    coercionType: "table",
    filterType: "onlyVisible"
},function(asyncResult){
    var values = (asyncResult.value.rows);
});
```

This code assumes you have already created a binding to the table. If not, you can run the following code first, which uses the table name to call [Bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/bindings.addfromnameditemasync):

```
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync("Table1","table",{
    id: "myTableBinding1"
},function(asyncResult){
    // handle errors and call code sample #1
});
```

Note that the solution above is supported as far back as Excel 2013 because it uses the shared APIs. The Excel-specific API set doesn't yet have the capability to return only unfiltered data.

-Michael Saunders, PM for Office add-ins

Comment: Hi Michael. Thank you so much for the workaround! It works great!
As a developer coming from VSTO Interop development I realize one has to think very differently when using the new Javascript API.

Comment: Michael, The function provided works excellent with fetching the filtered data, but as it seems to return a pure 2d array of rows where the filtered rows are removed, do you know of any way to retain the original unfiltered row number such that I can find back to the original cells after processing the filtered results?

Answer (score 2):

The upcoming next wave of features as part of Excel JS APIs 1.3 will include a new object "RangeView" that allows you to read only the visible values off the Range object.
Here's a link to the open spec on GitHub - https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/ExcelJs_1.3_OpenSpec/excel.
Note that this isn't available just yet, but will be in the near future.

Usage for your case off a table would look like this:

```
var table = tables.getItemAt(0);
var visibleView = table.getRange().getVisibleView();
ctx.load(visibleView);
ctx.sync().then(function () {
    var values = visibleView.values;
});
```

Comment: Hi Philip.
Brilliant! This is exactly what I need. Hopefully they will release this soon as our client is pushing us to complete this add-in as soon as possible. Meanwhile I guess I will have to do with no filter support.

Comment: I tried the workaround from Michael and it works to fetch filtered results from a bound table and will use that until 1.3 comes out. Thanks for the great info!

Comment: @MatsOftedal, the APIs that Philip mentioned are going to go to Beta fairly soon... you'll see the new changes once they're up on http://dev.office.com/changelog

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky Thanks! I will keep an eye on the changelog :-)