# Office.js Reading excel specific rows

Tags: excel, office-js, office365api, office365-apps, officedev

I am creating a excel table with office.js using addFromNamedItemAsync with table binding. This table will have thousands of rows. We have to read some specific row and save to backend.

Instead of using table.rows and iterate all the rows, is there a way to keep an identifiers to the rows, and access them directly?

May be adding a bookmark to some rows and accessing them directly? Please let me know if there is any ideas to bind rows/name the rows?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tried this myself, you could write a "bookmark" value to a column on the table and use Column [Filters](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/filter.md) to filter the table by that bookmark. Then you can read only the visible values as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38251467/157552